# Maximo: How to enable search in list tab in application where main object is view

Tags: view, maximo

Suggestions are appreciated.

1. I created DB view ABC_VW in maximo database.
2. Created object with name ABC_VW in maximo.
3. Created power application with name ABC with main object ABC_VW in maximo.

On list tab the search is disabled.
How can I enable the search?

Note: I tried updating search type to WILDCARD from backend in both tables MAXATTRIBUTE and MAXATTRIBUTECFG but no luck.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever a view is created in DB and object is created on the view, a primary column has to be updated in MAXATTRIBUTECFG table as

```
update maxattributecfg set changed='Y', searchtype='WILDCARD', primarykeycolseq='1', defaultvalue=null, maxtype='ALN', length=22 where objectname='ABC_VW' and attributename='XXXXXX';

update maxobjectcfg set CHANGED='A' where objectname in ('ABC_VW');
```

Then apply configuration changes from the Database Configuration.

This is how the field from view can made searchable.